# Find unique IP addresses in a MySQL table for a username

Tags: php, mysql, count, ip-address, unique

I have a table called link_track with the following fields: id, uid, ip, hitdate

id is an auto incrementing field

uid is the id of a member from the member table

ip is the ip address of site visitor which generated the new entry to the table

hitdate is the epoch date of the entry of the row to the table

Currently there are the following records in the table:

```
id   uid          ip           hitdate
28     1    71.61.59.113    1329016727
27     1    71.61.59.113    1329015378    
26     1    71.60.19.216    1329007376
```

**What I want to do is find all how many unique IP addresses exist for any one given uid**

Currently I am using the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) as `count` FROM `link_track` WHERE uid = '".$memID."'";

$results = mysql_query($query);

$statBuffer = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$unique_clicks = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $unique_clicks;
```

However this always return a value of 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a `COUNT()` aggregate from the database, and calling `mysql_num_rows()`.  The aggregate will always return only one row containing the number of IPs for that user (that's the `1` you're getting), so what you need instead is to get the value from `$statBuffer`

```
$unique_clicks = $statBuffer['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing SQL code instead of PHP you should run this query:

```
select distinct ip from link_track
where uid = $uid
```

However, I'd go for Michael suggestion, of course.